# Node/Express - one route/complex route code? or multiple-routes/simple route code?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, web, express, routes

Looking for a best practice guideline here on how to do CRUD and keep browser-code models synced with DB.  Context is an Angular/Express app and Postgres DB.

I have a UI edit form that shows a data record currently stored in DB. User can make changes, submit, and Express executes the update to Postgres.  After the update, I do a read operation to re-pull the data record so that my client-side model is synchronized with DB data.

So there are two trips to the DB here, the update AND the read.  My question is, is it better practice to 1) keep my Express route codes ultra-simple and do two Ajaxes from the browser (ajax on form submit, then after success response, another ajax to re-read the data from the DB), OR 2) do a single Ajax on form submit and have the Express route do the update, then read, then return the data to the browser?